# How to make the TEXTVIEW wrapped in a ScrollView clickable?

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/column"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="@string/column"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<com.example.demohlistview.InterceptScrollContainer
    android:id="@+id/scroollContainter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"         
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/column"
    android:focusable="false"
     >

    <com.example.demohlistview.MyHScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <View 
                android:layout_width="0.5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/lineColor"
                android:visibility="visible"
                 android:clickable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/column1"
                android:layout_width="85dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="@string/column1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
                />
            <View 
                android:layout_width="0.5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/lineColor"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/column2"
                android:layout_width="85dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="@string/column2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
                />
            <View 
                android:layout_width="0.5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/lineColor"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/column3"
                android:layout_width="85dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="@string/column3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </com.example.demohlistview.MyHScrollView>
</com.example.demohlistview.InterceptScrollContainer>
```

Here is MyHSrollView:

```
public class MyHScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {
ScrollViewObserver mScrollViewObserver = new ScrollViewObserver();

public MyHScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MyHScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MyHScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.i("pdwy","MyHScrollView onTouchEvent");
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {

    if (mScrollViewObserver != null /*&& (l != oldl || t != oldt)*/) {
        mScrollViewObserver.NotifyOnScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
}


public void AddOnScrollChangedListener(OnScrollChangedListener listener) {
    mScrollViewObserver.AddOnScrollChangedListener(listener);
}


public void RemoveOnScrollChangedListener(OnScrollChangedListener listener) {
    mScrollViewObserver.RemoveOnScrollChangedListener(listener);
}


public static interface OnScrollChangedListener {
    public void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt);
}


public static class ScrollViewObserver {
    List<OnScrollChangedListener> mList;

    public ScrollViewObserver() {
        super();
        mList = new ArrayList<OnScrollChangedListener>();
    }

    public void AddOnScrollChangedListener(OnScrollChangedListener listener) {
        mList.add(listener);
    }

    public void RemoveOnScrollChangedListener(
            OnScrollChangedListener listener) {
        mList.remove(listener);
    }

    public void NotifyOnScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        if (mList == null || mList.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {
            if (mList.get(i) != null) {
                mList.get(i).onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
ListView mListView1;
MyAdapter myAdapter;
RelativeLayout mHead;
LinearLayout main;
TextView text1;
private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mHead = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.head);

    mHead.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listHeadColor);
    mHead.setOnTouchListener(new ListViewAndHeadViewTouchLinstener());

    mListView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.item);
    mListView1.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    mListView1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionevent) {
            Log.e(TAG,"--------setOnTouchListener");
            HorizontalScrollView headSrcrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) mHead
                    .findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
            headSrcrollView.onTouchEvent(motionevent);

            return false;
        }
    });
    mListView1.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {
            MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder = (MyAdapter.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            holder.txt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i(TAG, "--------onclick");
                }
            });
            Log.e(TAG, "--------setOnItemClickListener");
            myAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();   
        }
    });

}

class ListViewAndHeadViewTouchLinstener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        HorizontalScrollView headSrcrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) mHead
                .findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
        headSrcrollView.onTouchEvent(arg1);
        return false;
    }
}

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public List<ViewHolder> mHolderList = new ArrayList<ViewHolder>();

    int id_row_layout;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private int selectedPosition = -1;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int id_row_layout) {
        super();
        this.id_row_layout = id_row_layout;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 250;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public void setSelectedPosition(int position) {
        this.selectedPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            synchronized (MainActivity.this) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(id_row_layout, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                MyHScrollView scrollView1 = (MyHScrollView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
                holder.scrollView = scrollView1;
                holder.txt = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.column);
                holder.txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.i("jacob", "tex.onClick()");

                    }
                });
                holder.txt1 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.column1);
                holder.txt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.i("jacob", "tex1111.onClick()!!!");

                    }
                });
                holder.txt2 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.column2);
                holder.txt3 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.column3);

                MyHScrollView headSrcrollView = (MyHScrollView) mHead
                        .findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
                headSrcrollView
                        .AddOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListenerImp(
                                scrollView1));
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                mHolderList.add(holder);
            }
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.txt.setText(position + "" + 11);

        holder.txt1.setText(position + "" + 1);

        holder.txt2.setText(position + "" + 2);
        holder.txt3.setText(position + "" + 3);

        int intervalColor1 = getResources().getColor(R.color.intervalColor1);
        int intervalColor2 = getResources().getColor(R.color.intervalColor2);
        int[] colors = { intervalColor1, intervalColor2};
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[position % 2]);
        if (selectedPosition == position) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }   

        return convertView;
    }

    class OnScrollChangedListenerImp implements OnScrollChangedListener {
        MyHScrollView mScrollViewArg;

        public OnScrollChangedListenerImp(MyHScrollView scrollViewar) {
            mScrollViewArg = scrollViewar;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
            mScrollViewArg.smoothScrollTo(l, t);
        }
    };

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView txt;
        TextView txt1;
        TextView txt2;
        TextView txt3;
        HorizontalScrollView scrollView;
    }
}// end class my
```

}

The `InterceptScrollContainer` goes here:

```
public class InterceptScrollContainer extends LinearLayout {

public InterceptScrollContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public InterceptScrollContainer(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    Log.i("pdwy","ScrollContainer onInterceptTouchEvent");
    return true;
}
```

}

What makes me confused is that the textview outside the scrollview is clickable and print tex.onClick() in the logcat, but the holder.tet1 is unclickable and isn't print "tex1111.onClick()!!!"

My question is how to make all the TEXTVIEW in my CUSTOM ScrollView clickable?  I think the click event is stopped somewhere and not pass on to the target textview

Comment: MyHScrollView how this class looks like ?

Comment: I have made the supplement

Comment: InterceptScrollContainer what does this view do ?

Comment: It is the subclass of LinearLayout and helps to layout the UI

Comment: Can you post all the code what ever you doing with the views, then may we will get some idea so that some one can help you out.

Comment: try to remove onItemClickListener for the view.

Comment: Does it caused by the confliction of onclick and ontouch event?

Comment: That was what I suppose to say and why you want onTouch and onclick at the same time.. You can stop listening to onTouch what change it gonna make.

Comment: I want to listen the ontouch of HorizonSrollView and Onclick of the TextView that are wrapped by the HorizonScrollView ,they are not the some thing .